# Blender 2.65 .blend file is not loading correctly in Blender 2.76b

Tags: blend-files, versions

I've just recently moving to Blender 2.76b from Blender 2.65. One of my .blend files made in 2.65 is not loading correctly when opened in 2.76b. When opened, one of the mesh is strange.

When viewed in Edit mode > wireframe display: 
1. Mesh lines are in different color and they seems broken (like unclear fax machine image).
2. Edge selection (only edge selection) gives no change of color which indicates that the edge is being selected, but it was selected.

When in viewed in Edit mode > solid display: 
1. Mesh lines are normal but the whole mesh is in different color.
2. Vertex, edge, and face selection is normal (they give different color when selected).
3. When using GLSL shading, the mesh does not display any texture, even though UVMapping is already done correctly (strangely, when in Object mode, the texture is displayed correctly).

When in viewed in Edit mode > texture display: 
1. When using GLSL shading, the mesh does not display any texture, even though UVMapping is already done correctly (strangely, when in Object mode, the texture is displayed correctly).
2. Mesh lines are normal but the whole mesh is in different color.
3. Vertex, edge, and face selection is normal (they give different color when selected).

Any explanation why this happens? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's to be expected. Blender 2.7 has broken some backwards compatibility (which is part of the reason why it took so long to be released).

> For 2.7x projects we will allow forward and (minor) backward compatibility breakage. That means that by default, the 2.7x .blend files don”t have to read reliably in 2.6x or older. Backward compatibility stays crucial though, and should only be acceptable for big and important improvements.

From the [Blender Roadmap for version 2.7](https://code.blender.org/2013/06/blender-roadmap-2-7-2-8-and-beyond/).

If it is essential to be able to open this file, I recommend using [version 2.69](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.69/).

Comment: Is using 2.69 could fix this problem in 2.76b (for example, loading in 2.69 and then save it and open it again in 2.76b)? It's only this one file that has problem, other files are OK. This is the file that I am still working on, so it is important.

Comment: I don't know, but you could rather easily test it :P Even if it doesn't, 2.69 is at least more feature-complete) than 2. 65.

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer. I still can revert back to 2.65 where the file is correctly loaded, but I can see that rendering in 2.76b is actually faster and more neat, and the ability to export to .3ds file. I'll try to use 2.69. Maybe it could provide a fix. Wonder if exporting this "broken file" to .3ds will result correctly or not. I'll try it myself. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: OK, I have solved the problem. The mesh with the problem actually has Show Weights in Mesh Display settings. After I turned it off, it's normal. Problem solved.